# ggplot stat_density2d bandwidth parameter not recognized

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

Using ggplot's stat_density2d layer, I cannot seem to adjust the bandwidth using the "h" parameter. No errors, but the bandwidth doesn't change. From the documentation, it seems h is passed to kde2d, or if NULL, then kde2d picks defaults. Something is not being passed, or perhaps I misunderstand.

An example:

```
df<-data.frame(x=rnorm(50), y=rnorm(50))
color<- colorRampPalette(c("white", "blue", "green", "red"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x,y = y))+
  stat_density2d(geom="tile", aes(fill=..density..), contour=FALSE, n=300, h=c(0.2,0.4)+ 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = color(100))
```

Regardless of h value (or vector of 2 values), nothing changes. The only other reference I could find to this issue is a bug report to Hadley from a few years ago where the issue was acknowledged and a workaround suggested.

https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/477

However, when I define stat_density2d parameters in lists like that, I get an error that stat_params and geom_params are not recognized.

Comment: This has been fixed in the development version: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/commit/d36e9193479ad43aac0842c07582afa3dd1a538a

Comment: Thanks, @Roland, I've just tried the development version and h is indeed working now. Because it sound like you would know, is the dev version generally stable?

Comment: No, it's not stable by definition. However, it will probably be pushed to CRAN relatively soon. But you'd have to ask Hadley for his schedule regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug and as Roland pointed out, it has been fixed in the development version available on github.

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")
```

I still am not able to define parameters in lists but that is a separate issue.